# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot `process` without `Compiler`

Tags: javascript, markdown, remarkjs, rehypejs

This is the code:

```
import remarkParse from 'remark-parse'
import rehypeSanitize from 'rehype-sanitize'
import rehypeStringify from "rehype-stringify"
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw"
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'
import remarkParse from 'remark-parse'
import remarkRehype from 'remark-rehype'
import {unified} from 'unified'

const markdownTable = `Here is a 200+ word response providing insights on the search query and suggested follow-up questions:

India and China are two of the world's largest producers of cement. Cement production is an important economic indicator, as the construction industry is a major driver of the economy in both countries. Tracking cement production over time can provide insights into infrastructure development, housing construction, and overall economic growth. 

A table comparing India and China's cement production over the last 5 years would look something like this:

| Year | India (million tonnes) | China (million tonnes) | 
|-|-|-|  
| 2019 | 337 | 2,200 |
| 2018 | 322 | 2,130 |
| 2017 | 297 | 2,410 | 
| 2016 | 283 | 2,350 |
| 2015 | 270 | 2,500 |

The table shows that China's cement production far exceeds India's, which is expected given the size of its economy. However, India's cement production has been steadily increasing over the past 5 years, reflecting its rapid infrastructure and housing growth. China's cement production peaked in 2014 and has slightly declined since then as its economy has matured.

### India vs China
`

const file = await unified()
  .use(remarkParse)
  .use(remarkRehype)
  .use(rehypeSanitize)
  .use(rehypeStringify)
  .process(markdownTable)

console.log("html(remarkParse):");
console.log(String(file))
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot `process` without `Compiler`
```

I have already checked [this](https://github.com/orgs/remarkjs/discussions/559) not sure it solves my problem.

I was suspecting some issue with contents of `markdownTable` variable but no matter what text I pass I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

changing `unified.process()` to `unified.parse()` resolved the issue.
I am not sure how exactly it works, I got the tip from [here](https://github.com/orgs/unifiedjs/discussions/113#discussioncomment-234473)

Comment: Strictly said it was there in the link in the question: https://github.com/orgs/remarkjs/discussions/559#discussioncomment-121030

Comment: @tevemadar great, now that you have understood it, if you can help me understand it too it would more awesome.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 I think there's a bug. rehype-stringify@10.0.0 gives this error but v9.0.4 doesn't.

Edit: I found this: https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype/issues/156

Comment: @orval glad that you found the bug . can you suggest the fix on their original thread on github.